# Separación de registros en columnas bajo un criterio

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Es posible realizar una consulta en la que se separen los registros en otras columnas a partir de un cierto criterio?

Por ejemplo:

```
Calificación || Tipo de Calificación

       1           Primer Parcial
       1           Primer Parcial
       3           Primer Parcial
       4           Segundo Parcial
       5           Segundo Parcial
       8           Segundo Parcial
       9           Segundo Parcial
       9           Tercer Parcial
```

Más o menos se puede dar a entender, de todas estas calificaciones ser divididas por el tipo de Calificación de la siguiente manera:

```
Primer Parcial || Segundo Parcial || Tercer Parcial

     1               4                 9      
     1               5                      
     3               8                       
                     9
```

Lo que estado haciendo es generar una consulta básica con el `where` sobre `Tipo de Calificación`:

```
select A. Calificación, B. Calificación,C. Calificación
  from (
           select Califacion where Tipo de Calificacion like 'Primer Parcial'
       ) as A
  left join (
           select Califacion where Tipo de Calificacion like 'Segundo Parcial'
       ) as B
  left join (
           select Califacion where Tipo de Calificacion like 'Tercer Parcial'
       ) as C
```

pero no creo que esta sea la mejor manera, ya que se estarían verificando todas las calificaciones para ver quiénes cubren lo señalado en el `where`.

Comment: ¿Para qué en este formato? No tiene mucho sentido presentar los datos de esta forma

Comment: Estoy utilizando PDFMaker para contruir un PDF, al momento de contruirlo los datos deben estar en el orden correspondiente a la tabla, me gustaria separarlos de esa manera ya que asi estaria en su columna apropiadamente y los demas irian vacios ya que no se cuenta con informacion

Comment: Si se puede tienes que utilizar la sentencia **Group By**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hasta el día de hoy la mejor opción que eh realizado es:

```
select A. Calificación, B. Calificación,C. Calificación
  from (
           select Califacion where Tipo de Calificacion like 'Primer 
Parcial'
       ) as A
  left join (
           select Califacion where Tipo de Calificacion like 'Segundo 
Parcial'
       ) as B
  left join (
           select Califacion where Tipo de Calificacion like 'Tercer 
Parcial'
       ) as C
```

Separar los valores de la misma tabla en 3 diferentes columnas y darles diferentes nombres para poder acceder únicamente a los valores que se requieren para la creación del documento PDF.